# Save float array to image (with EXR format)

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0

The following code does not work, it converts values to np.uint8 before writing image to disk.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
# Generate dummy gradient with float values
arr = np.arange(0,10,0.02)
arr = np.repeat(arr, arr.shape[0])
arr.reshape((500,500))
cv2.imwrite('output.exr',arr)
# At this point, returns True. Opening the image with OpenEXR 1.4 shows values have become UINT8 instead of Float
arr = cv2.imread('output.exr')
# Shape is (1000, 1000, 3)
print(arr[10,10])
array([0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8) # All float data is lost
```

As a little bonus, the documentation is very not helpful

```
$ pydoc cv2.imwrite
Help on built-in function imwrite in cv2:

cv2.imwrite = imwrite(...)
    imwrite(filename, img[, params]) -> retval
```

Doesn't say what the params should be...

How can I save an array with floating point values to EXR format ? (using OpenCV)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[imageio](https://pypi.org/project/imageio/) can save EXR files in any data format, (and it also supports a large amount of other image formats).

Pretty much a life saver for reading and writing most images:

```
import numpy as np
import imageio

# Generate dummy random image with float values
arr = np.random.uniform(0.0, 1.0, size=(500,500))

# freeimage lib only supports float32 not float64 arrays
arr = arr.astype("float32")

# Write to disk
imageio.imwrite('float_img.exr', arr)

# Read created exr from disk
img = imageio.imread('float_img.exr')

assert img.dtype == np.float32
```

Comment: Very helpful (+1).  I had to download "freeimage binary" per instructions on this page: https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format_exr-fi.html#exr-fi, for the `imwrite` command to work.  Though I am still trying to figure out why values changed slightly after loading the saved file (e.g., 1.0653863 changed to 1.0654297 in the same array location).

Comment: If you're seeing slight value changes, I don't know this for a fact but it's likely that EXR is not a lossless format (although visually you should never observe any difference)

Comment: This might be just a very important side note:
The above code does not work anymore straight away because np.random.uniform() creates an array in float64. This format is not supported by the freeimage lib. Therefore I suggest an edit:
```arr = arr.astype("float32")```
resolves the problem.

Comment: the above code gives me an error: ValueError: Could not find a format to write the specified file in single-image mode

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

`arr = cv2.imread("output.exr", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED).astype(np.float32)`

Comment: This does not work because the problem is at the export, not during loading. I've found a workaround, see my other question

Comment: Well maybe then you should add a link to your other question here