# Getting black image when saving it with cv2.imwrite

Tags: image, opencv

I am trying to save image after calculating local entropy of the image. I tried with `cv2.imwrite` but it saved black images. I tried with `io.imsave`. It saved the image but with a lossy conversion due to `float32` to `uint8` conversion. How to save the images without any loss?

Comment: For `io.imsave` I got below warning: `Lossy conversion from float64 to uint8. Range [3.1201322583795204, 7.110076508459596]. Convert image to uint8 prior to saving to suppress this warning.` How to solve this ?

Comment: Take a look at [Save float array to image (with EXR format)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45482307/save-float-array-to-image-with-exr-format)

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of choices. Either save to a format that supports floating point values, such as:

- TIFF
- PFM
- EXR - as suggested by @Rotem in the comments

Or, use `cv2.normalize()` to normalize your data's range and type to:

- 0..255 `uint8` and save as JPEG or PNG, or
- 0..65536 `uint16` and save as PNG.

---

In general, if an image looks black or nearly black, it is because the values are all low and the image has limited contrast. You can bump up the contrast very simply with **ImageMagick** in your Terminal with:

```
magick DARKIMAGE.png -auto-level OUTPUT.png
```

Comment: I like `skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(img, in_range='image', out_range=(0,255))`.  That does the same as ImageMagick -auto-level as it finds the input range automatically and allows you to specify 0 to 255 or 0 to 1 or as desired for the output range