# Saving RGBD as single image

Tags: python, rgb, depth

i used this code https://www.programmersought.com/article/8773686326/ to create RGBD by integrating RGB and depth image
now i wonder if that RGBD file could be saved as **single** image (jpeg,png...)
i tried it, but unsuccessfully, by using imageio.imwrite(), plt.imsave(), cv2.imwrite()... likely due dimension [4,64,1216], so is there a way to make it happen?

```
scale = (64, 1216)
 
resize_img = transforms.Resize(scale, Image.BILINEAR)
resize_depth = transforms.Resize(scale, Image.NEAREST)
to_tensor = transforms.ToTensor()
 
img_id = 0
 
# load image and resize
img = Image.open('RGB_image.jpg')
img = resize_img(img)
img = np.array(img)
 
# load depth and resize
depth = Image.open('depth_image.png')
depth = resize_depth(depth)
depth = np.array(depth)
depth = depth[:, :, np.newaxis]
 
# tensor shape and value, normalization
img = Image.fromarray(img).convert('RGB')
img = to_tensor(img).float()
 
depth = depth / 65535
depth = to_tensor(depth).float()

rgbd = torch.cat((img, depth), 0)
print("\n\nRGBD shape")
print(rgbd.shape)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: As per the spec, TIFF supports as many bands as you want. So first thing to try would be calling the methods you mentioned but use a filename ending in `".tif"`.

Comment: And make sure the dimension ordering is compatible with the method you use. I.e. does `[3, 64, 1216]` work or should it be `[1216, 64, 3]` or some other sequence.

Comment: @zemzem, Is there something you like me to change is my answer for better suiting your problem? We can use 16 bits Tiff format (for example) in case EXR format is too weird.

Comment: @Rotem well, actually yes
i tried your solution with EXR, and it didn't work 
best suit would be if images were saved as 4 channel png because it seems like neural network i work with supports only jpg and png format (network model is binary file so i can't make changes)
at the moment i am saving those 4 channel images as numpy arrays, dont think it will work but i'll give it a shot anyway

Comment: I updated my answer with PNG image format (`uint16` RGBA format). I have no way knowing if your training tool supports 16 bits per component RGBA PNG format, I have  posted an answer to your question "as is"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may save the depth as an alpha channel of an image in RGBA pixel format.

The alpha channel applies transparency channel, but we may use it as 4'th channel for storing RGB and Depth.

Since the depth may require high precision - may require `float32` precision, I suggest using [OpenEXR](https://www.openexr.com/) image format.
For compatibility with OpenEXR format we may convert all channels to `float32` in range [0, 1].

Note:

- I realized that [Open3D](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/tutorial/geometry/rgbd_image.html) supports RGBD images, but it looks like it doesn't support reading and writing the RGB and depth to a single file.

---

The following code sample uses OpenCV instead of Pillow.
I thought OpenCV supports EXR file format, but my OpenCV Python version is not built with EXR support. I used ImageIO package instead.

---

Stages for converting and writing RGB and depth to an EXR file:

- Load RGB image, resize it and convert to float:

  ```
   img = cv2.imread('RGB_image.jpg')  # The channels order is BGR due to OpenCV conventions.
   img = cv2.resize(img, scale, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
   img = img.astype(np.float32) / 255  # Convert to float in range [0, 1]
  ```
- Load depth image, resize and convert to float:

  ```
   depth = cv2.imread('depth_image.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)  # Assume depth_image.png is 16 bits grayscale.
   depth = cv2.resize(depth, scale, interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
   depth = depth.astype(np.float32) / 65535  # Convert to float in range [0, 1]
  ```
- Merge `img` (3 channels) and `depth` (1 channel) to 4 channels:
  The shape is going to be `(1216, 64, 4)` (applies OpenCV BGRA color convention).

  ```
   bgrd = np.dstack((img, depth))
  ```
- Writing `bgrd` to EXR file:
  If OpenCV is build with OpenEXR, we may use: `cv2.imwrite('rgbd.exr', bgrd)`.
  If we use ImageIO, we better to convert from BGRA to RGBA before saving:

  ```
   rgbd = cv2.cvtColor(bgrd, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2RGBA)
   imageio.imwrite('rgbd.exr', rgbd)
  ```

---

Code sample (convert RGB and Range to RGBA EXR file, then read and convert back):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import imageio

scale = (64, 1216)
 
# load image and resize
img = cv2.imread('RGB_image.jpg')  # The channels order is BGR due to OpenCV conventions.
img = cv2.resize(img, scale, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
img = img.astype(np.float32) / 255  # Convert to float in range [0, 1]
 
# load depth and resize
depth = cv2.imread('depth_image.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)  # Assume depth_image.png is 16 bits grayscale.
depth = cv2.resize(depth, scale, interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)

if depth.ndim == 3:
    depth = depth[:, :, 0]  # Keep one channel if depth has 3 channels?  depth = depth[:, :, np.newaxis]
 
depth = depth.astype(np.float32) / 65535  # Convert to float in range [0, 1]

# Use the depth channel as alpha channel (the channel order is BGRA - applies OpenCV conventions).
bgrd = np.dstack((img, depth))

print("\n\nRGBD shape")
print(bgrd.shape)

# Save the data to exr file (the color format of the exr file is RGBA).
# Error: cv::initOpenEXR imgcodecs: OpenEXR codec is disabled.
#cv2.imwrite('rgbd.exr', bgrd)

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45482307/save-float-array-to-image-with-exr-format
rgbd = cv2.cvtColor(bgrd, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2RGBA)
imageio.imwrite('rgbd.exr', rgbd)

################################################################################
# Reading the data:  

#bgrd = cv2.imread('rgbd.exr')  # Error: cv::initOpenEXR imgcodecs: OpenEXR codec is disabled.
rgbd = imageio.imread('rgbd.exr')

img = bgrd[:, :, 0:3]  # First 3 channels are the image.
depth = bgrd[:, :, 3]  # Last channel is the depth

img = (img*255).astype(np.uint8)  # Convert back to uint8
#depth = (depth*65535).astype(np.uint16)  # Convert back to uint16 (if required).

# Show images for testing:
cv2.imshow('img', cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2RGB))
cv2.imshow('depth', depth)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Note:

- You may have to make few modifications - I was not sure about the dimensions (`64x1216` or `1216x64`), and not sure about the code `depth = depth[:, :, np.newaxis]`.
  I may be wrong about the format of `depth_image.png`.

---

### Update:

**Saving 16 bits RGBA to PNG file:**

Instead of using EXR file and `float32` pixel format...
We may use PNG file and `uint16` pixel format.

The pixel format of the PNG file is going to be RGBA (RGB and Alpha - transparency channel).
Each color channel is going to be 16 bits (2 bytes).
The alpha channel stores the depth map (in `uint16` format).

- Convert `img` to `uint16` (we may choose not to scale by 256):

  ```
   img = img.astype(np.uint16)*256
  ```
- Merge `img` (3 channels) and `depth` (1 channel) to 4 channels:

  ```
   bgrd = np.dstack((img, depth))
  ```
- Save the merged image to PNG file:

  ```
   cv2.imwrite('rgbd.png', bgrd)
  ```

---

Code sample (the second part reads and display for testing):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

scale = (64, 1216)

# load image and resize
img = cv2.imread('RGB_image.jpg')  # The channels order is BGR due to OpenCV conventions.
img = cv2.resize(img, scale, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

# Convert the image to from 8 bits per color channel to 16 bits per color channel
# Notes:
# 1. We may choose not to scale by 256, the scaling is used only for viewers that expects [0, 65535] range.
# 2. Consider that most image viewers refers the alpha (transparency) channel, so image is going to look strange.
img = img.astype(np.uint16)*256

# load depth and resize
depth = cv2.imread('depth_image.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)  # Assume depth_image.png is 16 bits grayscale.
depth = cv2.resize(depth, scale, interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)

if depth.ndim == 3:
    depth = depth[:, :, 0]  # Keep one channel if depth has 3 channels?  depth = depth[:, :, np.newaxis]

if depth.dtype != np.uint16:
    depth = depth.astype(np.uint16)  # The depth supposed to be uint16, so code should not reach here.

# Use the depth channel as alpha channel (the channel order is BGRA - applies OpenCV conventions).
bgrd = np.dstack((img, depth))

print("\n\nRGBD shape")
print(bgrd.shape)  # (1216, 64, 4)

# Save the data to PNG file (the pixel format of the PNG file is 16 bits RGBA).
cv2.imwrite('rgbd.png', bgrd)


# Testing:
################################################################################
# Reading the data:
bgrd = cv2.imread('rgbd.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

img = bgrd[:, :, 0:3]  # First 3 channels are the image.
depth = bgrd[:, :, 3]  # Last channel is the depth

#img = (img // 256).astype(np.uint8)  # Convert back to uint8

# Show images for testing:
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.imshow('depth', depth)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```